# Why "Object[] object = new String[][]" compiles? - Java

Tags: java, arrays

Why does this code compile?

```
Object[] object = new String[5][5];
```

I mean, why can I do that if I'm creating an array object with different dimensions than specified in the reference variable?

This doesn't compile:

```
String[] strings = new String[5][5];
```

So what is happening here?

Comment: Remember that an array is an `Object` in Java.

Comment: Arrays, in this case a String array, are considered Objects too. Try Object obj = new String[],and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one compiles because `String[]` is an `Object`. The 2nd one doesn't compiles because `String` is not `String[]`.

```
Object[] object = new String[5][5];  // Means each element is an String[] which is an Object as well.

String[] strings = new String[5][5]; // Also Means each element is an String[] which is not same as just String.
```

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Arrays in Java are [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). For any types `T1` and `T2`, if `T2` derives from `T1` (that is, `T2` directly or indirectly extends or implements `T1`), then `T2[]` is a subtype of `T1[]`. Thus, `String[]` is a subtype of `Object[]` and you can assign an object of type `String[]` to a variable of type `Object[]`.

Note (as Oli Charlesworth points out in the comment), covariance breaks Java's compile-time type safety. This code:

```
Object [] o = new String[5];
o[0] = Integer.valueOf(3);
```

will generate an `ArrayStoreException` at run time when the second line tries to execute. So I'm not suggesting that covariant arrays are a great thing; it's just that's how the language works.

Regarding your second example, a `String[]` is not a `String[][]`. Covariance does not apply because `String[]` does not derive from `String`. However, you could do:

```
Object[] o = new String[5][5];
```

because a `String[]` is, in fact, an `Object`.

Comment: Which is fine until you do `String[] strings = new String[5]; Object[] objs = strings; objs[0] = new Integer(42);`...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Thanks for that. I added something about it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any array is itself an `Object`.

Thus, by this rule:
 `String[5]` is an `Object`.
`String[5][]` is an `Object[]`.
`String[5][]` and `String[5]` are `Object`s too.

The distinction matters when one wants to enforce compiler to deal with an array or multi-array, but not a simple `Object`.

For all types other than `Object`, this rule does not apply and then:
`String[5][5]` **IS NOT** a `String[]`

Answer (score 1):

An array of Strings (so String[5] for example) can be considered as an Object. Same for two-dimensional array (or array of arrays). However, a double-dimensional array of Strings is not a single-dimensional array of Strings, so you can't assign 1-dim array of Strings to 2-dim array of Strings.

Also notice, that in Java (and not only) a two-dimensional array is basically an array of arrays. Therefore in the example you gave, you can assign a two-dimensional array (an array of arrays) of Strings to an array of Objects (so at every index of the Object array you store a single-dimensional array of Strings), but you can't do it with Strings.

Answer (score 0):

1- for the first code you can't be able to use string methods as

```
object[0][0].substring(1);//error
//correct to use string methods
strings[0][0].substring(1);
strings[0][0].chartAt(0);
```

but the second code you can use string methods.

2- second code must be as:

```
String[][] strings = new String[5][5];
```